# Email Sending in C# the remote host not responding

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am trying to create an email client via C# but I keep on having problems and I don't know how to proceed. I don't experience any problems when I am using gmail and yahoo as the smtp host. I am also not experiencing problems when I send mails to the company mail using google.

The problems shows up whenever I send Email using the company email address. You can address the email on a browser.

I am also not using a private internet connection separate from the company access to the internet

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace email
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Net.NetworkCredential networkcreds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            try
            {
                //setup for smtp host
                client.Host = "mail.company.com";
                client.Port = 25;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = networkcreds;
                client.EnableSsl = true;

                //convert strings to mailaddress
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("username@company.com");
                MailAddress froms = new MailAddress("username@company.com");

                //set up message settings
                message.Subject = "TEST SUBJECT";
                message.Body = "TEST BODY";
                message.To.Add(to);
                message.From = froms;

                client.Send(message);
                MessageBox.Show("Message Sent");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Message Not sent");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error that I find in the try catch:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 203.82.36.171:25
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at email.Form1.send_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Jake Andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\email\email\Form1.cs:line 50
```

Comment: You are trying to connect to `mail.company.com` which you can't connect to. You obviously need a valid `smtp` server to connect to, not the one in the example.

Comment: I'd assume that either that SMTP address is not correct or the IP you're using to connect to it hasn't got permission/registered to connect/send mail from that server

Comment: Hope this code work helps you.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58463209/6773798

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping the mail-server:

```bash
ping 203.82.36.171
```

If that works there are several other options to check. For example, my company does not allow every client to send mails with the SMTP protocol - ask if you have the rights to send mail via SMTP from your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with another port.

```
client.Port = 465;
```