# Email sending in C# ASP.NET query SMTP PORT

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

we use the SMTP ports 587 for sending emails through gmail associated account in C# ASP.NET. So how can we apply a port/host to send emails from any account like yahoo,outlook etc?

Comment: keep those values in a config file and read from there. When you want to update your host, just update your config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by:

1. Identify if the mail services expose SMTP ports for public use
2. Programatically switch the host/port according to the service the code is talking to.

Something like

If the email address is yahoo, then connect to yahoo SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the SMTP information in web.config [(read about how to do this)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then in you code do something like this:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("admin@google.com");
message.Subject = "Hello";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("admin@google.com");
message.Body = "Hello world.";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("host_name_defined_in_web_config");
smtp.Send(message);
```

If you wrap this code into a method (say, `MyOwnMailSender.Send()`) you can simplify it further, for example you can then invoke:

```
MyOwnMailSender.Send(addresses, title, body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for setting the host and port sections of a new SMTP Object

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "testpass");
smtp.Host = "mail.test.co.uk";
smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32("22");
```

Then you could call it in a switch statement

```
switch(account){
      case "yahoo" :
      sendmailYahoo();
      break;
      case  "hotmail" :
      sendmailHotmail();
      break;
}
```

obviously with this case you would have seperate methods or you could call it during the method so you could have

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

switch(account){
      case "yahoo" :
      smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yahoo", "testpass");
      smtp.Host = "mail.yeahoo.co.uk";
      smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32("212");
      break;
      case  "hotmail" :
       smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("hotmail", "testpass");
       smtp.Host = "mail.hotmail.co.uk";
       smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32("232");
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx), you can configure the port in the web.config file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
        <network
          clientDomain="www.contoso.com"
          defaultCredentials="true"
          enableSsl="false"
          host="mail.contoso.com"
          port="25"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms164242.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
       public void MailSend()
        {
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("mail@gmail.com");
                mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
                mailMessage.Body = "body";
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(mail));


                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = mailMessage.From.Address;
                NetworkCred.Password = "password";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the Working Code of SMTP Email Sender**

```
  public static bool SendEmail(string attachment)
    {
        try
        {
            string smtp = "smtp.gmail.com";
            int port = 587;
            string from = "Gmail Account";
            string password = "Account Password";
            string DisplayName = "Email Subject";
            bool IsHTML = false;
            bool IsSSLEnable = true;
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtp);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from, DisplayName);
            mail.To.Add("Reciever Email");
            mail.Subject = DisplayName ;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = IsHTML;
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));
            mail.Body = "This is auto Generated Report";
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, password);
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = IsSSLEnable;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```